# SQLite3::createFunction vs internal php function

Tags: php, sqlite

what is advantages of using SQLite3::createFunction() over simple php function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it in SQL-queries

```
SELECT col1, my_function(col2) FROM tab;
```

With PHP-functions you must iterate over the result set on your own. I don't know, how exactly it is implemented, but as far as I know `SQLite3` works with cursors and therefore the function should only get executed, when you retrieved a row.

Comment: i mean using sqlite::create_function() instead of php function will make the performance better?

Comment: Maybe, I didn't test it myself, but I assume, that it wont make the performance worse. I would even keep performance considerations out of scope at first. "Premature Optimization" and such